# How to find a command ID for a key binding in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse (3.x for that matter) you can use the **Plug-in Spy** and **Menu Selection Spy** to find out information about UI elements which are accessible via the mouse.

I am now facing the problem that I want to find out about the command (I need the command id) which is triggered by a certain key binding, because I want to create a menu item for this command in my custom UI (view/editor)).

In my concrete case I am looking for the *Expand All children* command which is triggered by *Numpad+Plus* in a common navigator. However, I am interested in a general way to find out about key bindings.

I know that I can access the key bindings via the preferences dialog or the key binding QuickView (*CTRL+SHIFT+L* in Windows); but there, I can only find out about the command name, not the ID or the contributing plug-in of the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Eclipse `Search / Plug-in Search` to search for an extension point. In this case search for `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` to see the key bindings:
[image: Search dialog]

The search will give to a list of plug-ins, open a list item to see the plugin.xml for the plug-in with the extension point highlighted. You will have to search through the plug-ins and entries to find what you want.

The `Expand All` key binding is defined in the `org.eclipse.ui` plug-in and has command id `org.eclipse.ui.navigate.expandAll`

You may need to check the `Include all plug-ins from target in Java search` in `Preferences > Plug-in Development` to get the search to look in the target platform (which needs to be Eclipse).

Comment: Ok, I forgot about the Plugin search. But this only gets me all contributing plug-ins. I'd have to manually browse through all of them (or take a guess where it could be located).

Comment: It is generally not hard to guess which plugins are likely.

Comment: Accepted the answer. Yet, for some scenarios the tracing approach I have found, seems to be better suited. (see the respective answer).

Answer (score 6):

I have found an alternative which suits my requirements a bit more.

[This article](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/07/08/tip-tracing-keybindings-in-rcp/) describes how to turn on tracing of the keybinding mechanism. This will report each keypress and triggered shortcut/keybinding to the console.

> In the launch configuration dialog, go to the *Tracing* tab and enable general tracing.
>   Then select the plug-in `org.eclipse.ui` and activate the options:
>
> `org.eclipse.ui/debug`
>   `org.eclipse.ui/trace/keyBindings`
>   `org.eclipse.ui/trace/keyBindings.verbose`

It's not super-convenient, but it serves my purpose and does not require me to take a guess on the contributing plug-ins. (At least if the contributing plug-in is not obvious).

Comment: Just a note to say this is equivalent to the -debug command line option with the tracing options in a file (so you can do this for an installed Eclipse as well).

Comment: In my case, this was far more efficient than having to step through each matched plug-in from using the Plug-in search. Here I just had to launch with tracing and trigger the keybinding to find its plug-in, readily printed to the Console view.

Comment: I had to enable org.eclipse.ui/trace/commands. The trace/keyBindings and trace/keyBindings.verbose are not necessary then. Further, I think this is super-convenient! Thanks a lot :)