# Provide default shortcut to open custom Eclipse view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin that contributes a view. Eclipse seems to provide an action that can be associated with keyboard shortcuts to open all sorts of views, including my new custom view. You can find these shortcuts in Preferences > General > Keys > "Show View (VIEWNAME)".

Now, I just want to provide a default shortcut for this action. So I want to tell Eclipse which shortcut to use for the "Show View (MY_VIEW)" action. This action seems to be generated automatically by Eclipse so I do not know how to configure it. Is there some extension point for this?

Preferences Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: 'Show In' isn't the show view command - it is the 'Show In' menu in the context menu of an editor. It shows the file currently being edited in a particular view.

Comment: You are right. However, there are also actions for "Show View (VIEWNAME)". I adjusted my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point and using the existing `org.eclipse.ui.views.showView` command. You provide the id of the view to open as a parameter to the command.

For example the 'Show View (Breakpoints)' shortcut is defined like this:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
     commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
     schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
     sequence="M2+M3+Q B">
     <parameter
          id="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
          value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.BreakpointView">
     </parameter>
 </key>
</extension>
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to find existing xml definitions like this one? Some sort of plugin xml browser for installed stuff? Other example: How to find out what is the id of the view category for "General", "Debug", or "Team"?

Comment: The normal 'Seach > Plug-in Search' can search all the Eclipse code. In the Preferences look at 'Plug-in Development' and select 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java workspace scope'. You can also install the 'Eclipse SDK' to see the source code.

Comment: Another idea to find existing extensions and Eclipse code in general: Use Google and only look for some file type.
Example: search for (without quotes) "eclipse org.eclipse.ui.views general category filetype:xml" to find some plugin.xml files or search for "eclipse open resources dialog filetype:java" to find some Java code (in this case for the Open Resource dialog).

Comment: One can also trace the executed commands in Eclipse. So you can print the commandId to the console, e.g., when the corresponding shortcut is pressed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241151/how-to-find-a-command-id-for-a-key-binding-in-eclipse